# does .appened affect the order of arguments in list?

Tags: python

I ran the below code:

```
names = ["Carol", "Albert", "Ben", "Donna"]
names.append("Eugenia")
print(sorted(names))
```

and I got:

```
['Albert', 'Ben', 'Carol', 'Donna', 'Eugenia']
```

`.append` should add the element at the end of list, but order of elements got changed, why the result isn't `['Carol', 'Albert', 'Ben', 'Donna', 'Eugenia']`?

Comment: Because you call `sorted(names)`? What do you think sorting the list does?

Comment: you are sorting it , what do you expect!!

Comment: And, just to be clear, the LIST still contains exactly what you described, unsorted.  You just printed out a sorted copy of the list.

Comment: Not only is it baffling that you apparently didn't expecting sorting to change the order, the value you appended is at the end **either way**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After appending "Eugenia", you're sorting the list before printing (with `sorted`). Append merely places a new element at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to remove the sorted method?

```
names = ["Carol", "Albert", "Ben", "Donna"]
names.append("Eugenia")
print(names)
```

Outputs `['Carol', 'Albert', 'Ben', 'Donna', 'Eugenia']`